# Where is it legal to specify a preprocessor directive?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I'm trying to write a state machine that slurps a source file and splits it into sections that are either the compiler's business or the preprocessor's business.  Not a deep traversal, I'm just looking for sections that are either comments or preprocessor directives. (no macros, no conditionally compiled blocks, etc.)

Comments are simple enough, but I'm not 100% sure where it's legal to specify a preprocessor directive.  For example, is the following line legal?

```
int i; #include <derp.h>
```

Are there any special cases where some directives are allowed and others are not?

I've searched google and SO and not found a question which answers this.

Please answer for BOTH **C** and C++, I tagged both knowingly and intentionally.

Comment: If you're trying to make a parser, you really should be using the definitive grammar for the language (i.e. the standard(s)), rather than relying on answers given by fallible mortals here on SO!

Comment: have you even tried google?

Comment: Yes, I've tried google.  It says so, right there in the question.

Comment: `... that slurps a source file` - such imagery.  BTW `#includes files` are not supposed to end in hanging comments, double quotes, single quotes, etc., but invalid ones do.  Maybe an _interestingly_ placed `#include` is attempting such behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Preprocessor directives can appear anywhere, as long as they're the first non-whitespace token on the line.  Accordingly, you can't write

```
int i; #define ThisIsntLegal SinceItsNotAtTheStart
```

But this would be:

```
int i;
#define Woohoo ThisIsLegal
```

Hope this helps!

[C11 Standard (N1570, ISO/IEC 9899:201x)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (Relevant section: s6.10 Prerocessing Directives, page 160)

Comment: Do you have a link to a resource that says this?  Anecdotal "throw it at a compiler and see what it does" testing supports this, but I want to see it in writing. :D

Comment: @Wug: As I suggested above, the place to find this in writing is the language standard(s) ;)

Comment: +1.  If you want a standards link, *C11 s6.10 Preprocessing directives* seems to cover this

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I edit a link to the standards document into your answer.

Comment: Interestingly enough, both GCC and MSVC allow you to compile and run the following: http://ideone.com/pensQP